# Why list.length returns 1 size if no elements are present

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a werid problem with returning size of list.
Server has `List<String>`  as return type. In response of flutter request I get String.

```
I/flutter ( 4454): ["Email is already taken","Phone number is already taken","Username is already taken"]
I/flutter ( 4454): [Email is already taken, Phone number is already taken, Username is already taken]
I/flutter ( 4454): 3
I/flutter ( 4454): false
```

So I convert it to list, removing `"` and `[` and `]` like this:

```
 print(response.body);
    List<String> list = response.body
        .substring(1, response.body.length - 1)
        .replaceAll('"', '')
        .split(',')
        .toList();

 print(list);
    print(list.length);
    print(list.length == 0);
```

and here is everything correct, but when I get no errors (after printing):

```
I/flutter ( 4454): []
I/flutter ( 4454): []
I/flutter ( 4454): 1
I/flutter ( 4454): false
```

It returns 1 size despite list has no elements.

Could you tell me what am I doing wrong? Also why response.body contains String when server side returns `List<String>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list does contain one element, the empty `String` with the value: `''`. The reason why you are not seeing it when printing the list, is because Dart does not add anything to strings when printing them (e.g. encapsulate it with `""`).

We can see this in this example:

```
void main() {
  final list = [''];
  print(list); // []

  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    print('$i = ${list[i]}'); // 0 = 
  }
}
```

It seems to me that you are trying to parse some JSON manually. Instead of doing it yourself you can do something like this in your example:

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  const input = r'["Email is already taken","Phone number is already taken","Username is already taken"]';
  print(parseJsonList(input));
  // [Email is already taken, Phone number is already taken, Username is already taken]
}

List<String> parseJsonList(String json) =>
    (jsonDecode(json) as List<dynamic>).cast<String>();
```

Comment: but if I change to `.substring(0....)` then if list contains some elements I have double '[' = [[Email is already taken, Phone number is already taken, Username is already taken]`

Comment: Ok, cannot help you with that part. The question was about why an seemingly empty list would have the lenght of one. :)

Comment: Okay. But Why do I have this empty string? I do not understand it. Ahmed Raza's answer does not work.

Comment: @traki111 Any reason why you are making this parsing yourself instead of just decode with the JSON parser?

Comment: because json.decode returns `List<dynamic>` and it's very unhandy. Are there any better decoders?

Comment: @traki111 See my suggested solution. I have added a cast.

Answer (score 0):

change this `.substring(1, response.body.length - 1)` with `.substring(0, response.body.length - 1)`